# Kendo Upload - Limit Number of Concurrent Async Uploads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We use the Kendo Upload  to allow customers to upload large number of files for processing. Some of our customers in countries with poorer internet have run into bandwidth restrictions when trying to upload a large number of files (i.e a 100 files) simultaneously. The files themselves are not very large, but the number of files causes a problem.

To get around this, is it possible to set a upper limit on the number of async uploads that may be in progress at any given time?

So that if there are 20 files selected and added, I'd like them to  upload in 2 batches of 10.

Or are the other ways to do this?

Thanks in advance

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Try the `select` event:

```
var onSelect = function(e) {
    if(e.files.length > 10) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Uploads limited to 10 files at a time.');
    }
};

// initialize and configure an Upload widget with a select event handler
$("#photos").kendoUpload({
    // ...
    select: onSelect
});
```

Modified from the Kendo UI documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload#events-select

Comment: That solves the problem by limiting the many files are initially added. It doesn't do anything about how many files are uploaded at a time. If there are 20 files selected and added, I'd like them uploaded in 2 batches of 10....

Comment: There's no way of doing that. I just did a test on their demo site with over 100 files and it looks like it only does a few at a time. This might not be the cause of your problem. http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/async.html